# How can i obtain real ether in metamask (at the same manner i obtain ether from ropsten faucet in testnet) to create real transactions in mainnet?

Tags: metamask, wallets, mainnet

How to obtain real Ether to create Transactions in mainnet via metamask? because i create transactions with ether from faucet.ropsten.be but this is not real ether.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain real Ether, you need to buy it. You buy it from a cryptocurrency exchange with fiat money (US Dollar, Euros, whatever is your national currency).

Answer (score 0):

As said above - you can buy real ETH with fiat. Metamask has an on-ramp for Fiat to Crypto. Just click the buy button. Can also buy from various wallets such as MyCrypto (no-bias lol) and Coinbase.

Comment: Cool! i don´t know metamask can do it, thank´s